# Why Some SMPS use Tiny Switch, Some use Top Switch and Some use Link Switch and Other use PWM IC. Please guide what is the criteria to select?

Tags: pwm, switch-mode-power-supply

I saw many smps design , Some use Tiny Switch , Top Switch , Link Switch and other user PWM Control IC only. What is the difference and how to choose right one??

Comment: It's awesome that you have looked up a bunch of reference designs.  But please post the links to them.  That would save the rest of us time and clicks.

Comment: Upvote for obvious signs of work done, and an interesting question. +1 Nick for needing more info. This question could benefit from being slightly more specific, but I like it.

Comment: Market forces. People will use the cheapest device that that meets what they need (specs, quality, longevity, ...) or can get away with.

Comment: Top Switch was popular in PC power supplies as a housekeeper.When I would fix These PSUs it was almost always the TOPSWITCH that failed .I wouild say that TOPSWITCH is a bad beetle.

Comment: @Autistic I think tinyswitch are mostly used in the STANDBY section of most of the ATX SMPS modules, is there a quick way to test them in the smps?

Answer (score 3):

It's all about power delivery to the load: -

[image]

Taken from [this](http://www.power.com/sites/default/files/product-docs/highpwr_selectorguide.pdf) data sheet

PWM control ICs require an external MOSFET (it's built into power integrations switch products listed above) and because it has an external MOSFET you can tailor the design for more specific applications or even higher powers.

Comment: Hi thanks to everyone for you time and help. I got answer from last comment.